# Keep :before content and element content together

Tags: html, css

Consider the following HTML/CSS:

***HTML***

```
<h5>Actual</h5>
<p id="content">
    Hello <a class="textLink" href="#">World</a>
</p>
```

***CSS***

```
p#content {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 65px;
}

a.textLink:before {
    content: ">> ";
}
```

This will render as such:

[image: Actual render result]

How can I achieve it so, that the `:before` content will not break, but instead be snapped to the element content, to produce a result like this:

[image: Desired result]

Of course, this can only happen if there is enough space for the content, but just to prove there is, we can use this

***HTML***

```
<h5>Desired</h5>
<p id="content">
    Hello<br/><a class="textLink" href="#">World</a>
</p>
```

Which will provide the desired result. Only; how can I do this without inserting manual `<br>`eaks?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h4ycywb6/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the case when you need to use [non-breaking space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space) `&nbsp;`. If it was HTML content then you would use `<a class="textLink" href="#">&nbsp;World</a>`. However you need to use unicode encoded form of it `U+00A0` in `:before`, which will look like this:

```css
p#content {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 65px;
}

a.textLink:before {
    content: ">>\00A0";
}
```

```html
<h5>Actual</h5>
<p id="content">
    Hello <a class="textLink" href="#">World</a>
</p>
```

Comment: I thinks this is closer to what needs to be done, than setting "inline-block" from @Akshay as it uses a more semantic approach, than what feels like more of a layout-hack

Answer (score 3):

You can use `display:inline-block` on the `a` element

```css
p#content {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 65px;
}
a{
    display:inline-block;
}
a.textLink:before {
    content:">> ";
}
```

```html
<h5>Actual</h5>
<p id="content">
    Hello <a class="textLink" href="#">World</a>
</p>

<h5>Desired</h5>
<p id="content">Hello
    <br/><a class="textLink" href="#">World</a>
</p>
```

Comment: Note, that `inline-block` will not work if the `p#content` width is a little smaller, say `60px`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/mkufymqr/1/

```
a.textLink:before {
    content: " >>";
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what you did to fix it?

Comment: i added an extra space before >> , and this will work